# Can't access classes inside a react-modal

Tags: html, css, reactjs

This is my first time using react and I am sure that code given is probably not using react's best practices but I am just playing around with it to understand it for now, my problem is that I am trying to access the divs and paragraphs inside the modal but document querySelector returns null. Any ideas? Thanks

```js
moreInfo(movie) {
  const movieModalImg = document.querySelector(".movieModalImg");
  const movieModalTitle = document.querySelector(".movieModalTitle");
  const movieModalRunTimeNum = document.querySelector(
    ".movieModalRunTimeNum"
  );
}

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div id="modal">
        <Modal
          isOpen={this.state.setIsOpen}
          onRequestClose={this.closeModal.bind(this)}
          contentLabel="Example Modal"
        >
          <a className="closeModalBtn" onClick={this.closeModal} href={"#"}>
            &times;
          </a>
          <div className="modal-wrapper">
            <div>
              <img src={moviePoster} className="movieModalImg" alt=""></img>
            </div>
            <p className="movieModalTitle"></p>

            <div className="movieModalRunTime">
              <h4>Runtime:</h4>
              <p className="movieModalRunTimeNum"></p>
              <p>Minutes</p>
            </div>

            <div className="movieModalProductionCountry">
              <h4>Production Countries:</h4>
              <p className="movieModalProductionCountries"></p>
            </div>

            <div className="movieModalVoteCount">
              <h4>Vote Count:</h4>
              <p className="movieModalVoteCountNum"></p>
            </div>

            <div className="movieModalRevenew">
              <h4>Revenew:</h4>
              <p className="movieModalRevenewNum"></p>
              <p>$</p>
            </div>

            <div className="movieModalBudget">
              <h4>Budget:</h4>
              <p className="movieModalBudgetNum"></p>
              <p>$</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </Modal>
      </div>
      <a
        href="#"
        className="movieCoverMoreInfo"
        onClick={this.moreInfo.bind(this)}
      >
        <img className="moreInfoIcon" src={info} alt=""></img>
        More Info
      </a>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Do you need to use `.bind(this)`? Are you using ES5? Might be a scoping issue

Comment: Can you share this on code editor? because it looks fine in this code.